# How to use Fuzzy Topic Model as a Classification Model Input

Tags: python, nlp, topic-modeling, fuzzy-logic

I have fuzzy clustering for Topic modelling and got this
[image].
There are all total 50 topics[0 to 49] and each topic consists 30 words with a probability multiplicative factor. Now how do I make it as a Classifier input. My final goal to document classification.

**Demo**

```
pip install octis
pip install FuzzyTM
from octis.dataset.dataset import Dataset
dataset = Dataset()
dataset.fetch_dataset('DBLP')
data = dataset._Dataset__corpus
print(data[0:5])
pwgt, ptgd = flsaW1.get_matrices()
topics = flsaW1.show_topics()
topics
```

Answer (score 0):

`flsaW.get_matrices()` returns two matrices.
Lets define `n` as the amount documents, `k` as the amount topics and `m` as the amount of words in the corpus.

The first matrix represents the word-topic distribution and has shape `(m,k)`.
This matrix holds the values that represent how much each word "belongs" to a topic. The second matrix represents the topic-document distribution and has shape `(k,n)`. This matrix hold the values that represent how much a particular topic is present in each document.

If you would like to turn this into a classification task, you could use the topics as features and feed the topic-document distribution to a classifier model (e.g. Logistic Regression).

To be detailed, you need to transpose it before you can use it as input.

```
pwgt, ptgd = flsaW1.get_matrices()
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(ptgd.T, y_true)
```

A full example can be found below

```
from octis.dataset.dataset import Dataset
from FuzzyTM import FLSA_W
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np

dataset = Dataset()
dataset.fetch_dataset('DBLP')
data = dataset._Dataset__corpus
flsaW1 = FLSA_W(data, num_topics=50)
pwgt, ptgd = flsaW1.get_matrices()

y_true = np.random.randint(2, size=ptgd.shape[1])
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(ptgd[:,:5000].T, y_true[:5000]) # Splitting in a train set
y_pred = model.predict(ptgd[:,5000:].T)   # and a test set 
print(accuracy_score(y_true[5000:], y_pred)) # accuracy is 0.5 because labels are random
```